# Will a google colab notebook connected to a local GPU/runtime ever disconnect?

Tags: runtime, google-colaboratory, local

I am running a google colab notebook using my local GPU therefore using the colab feature of connecting to a local runtime.

I was wondering if, when running colab this way, it will remain with the same issues of disconnecting the runtime after a few hours being idle while training a model.

Thanks in advance,
Pedro

Answer (score 1):

I have found by experience that when google colab is connected to a local runtime (i.e. GPU on your own machine as an example) it will never disconnect.

The 12h limit only applies when using google resources, since in this way they are not being used, it does not apply.

Answer (score -1):

Notebooks run by connecting to virtual machines that have maximum lifetimes that can be as much as 12 hours. Notebooks will also disconnect from VMs when left idle for too long. However maximum VM lifetime and idle timeout behavior may vary over time, or based on your usage because this is necessary for Colab to be able to offer computational resources free of charge